# AdMob crashes with [GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, admob

I have installed the AdMob SDK 6.2.0 (Xcode 4.5 (4G182) and I am testing on an iPhone 4S and the simulator). I followed the tutorial and just want to get AdMob showing a banner once. But it crashes on the last line:

```
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                        self.view.frame.size.height -
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

self.bannerView.delegate = self;
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"xREMOVEDBYMEx";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
GADRequest * request = [GADRequest request];
request.testing = YES;
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

The crash is

> 2012-09-28 09:03:58.268 NewProject[1467:c07] -[GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x95c17d0
>   2012-09-28 09:03:58.276 NewProject[1467:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x95c17d0'

This looks like a bug in the library to me but I think thats very unlikely. Any thoughts?

EDIT: The exact same code works in the example projects. Is there something I can do wrong with my project file that would result in that error?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You need to add `-ObjC` to the *Other Linker Flags* of your application target's build setting:

1. Click the blue top-level project icon in XCode
2. Choose your target and go to *Build Settings*
3. Under *Other Linker Flags* add `-ObjC` for both *Release* and *Debug*

Source: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation#ios-linker

Also be sure to do a clean and rebuild

Comment: my project won't compile with -all_load flag, but it seems to work without crash now after added -ObjC. Could you explain this?

Comment: @bart: As a small christmas present I've updated this answer to contain the necessary information from the link and undeleted it. The next time please do it on your own though.

Comment: Why is it necessary to do so?

Comment: cocos2d projects seem to start with this flag.

Comment: My God, project worked without this flag for years. And suddenly started to crash. WHY??? Why do I need this flag??? Any explanation?

Comment: I tried this in my project but it didn't work. My app still crashes. Any idea?

Comment: It's not a solutions if u use Deployment iOS target 6 and more. It's will crash on compiling with facebook framework.

Comment: FYI Does not work for iOS 10 and above on Xcode 8 as far as I know. My project already has that flag and I installed Firebase and Admob through Cocoapods, still get error.

Comment: Ignore that comment. ^ my error was that the UIView object was not set to the GAD class.

Answer (score 4):

Best solution for me is use -force_load flag instead -ObjC
[image]

Comment: With the "-ObjC" flag I was having problems with ASIHTTP.
The best solution is use the flag above "-force_load". Tks! ;P

Comment: this will fully load only this library and reduce App size too, thumbs up

Comment: Does not work on Xcode 8. Taking off -ObjC gives a linker error code 1.

Answer (score 3):

If you guys are still having trouble, make sure it's -ObjC and not -Objc. Geez, spent weeks trying to figure out why.

Comment: Almost everything is case sensitive in most programming language.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who tried adding the Obj-c linker flag and still got the same "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error when trying to load an ad I found a fix. This is for the newest XCode (version 8.1).

For reference:

- I added Google AdMob using cocoapods.
- I used storyboard to make an outlet connection to my viewcontroller and GADBannerView was **NOT** available as a class so I wrote it in like most people did.
- On one of the stackoverflow answers that I saw the  custom class for the bannerview was set to GADBannerView, which I assume would happen automatically if it was an option in the dropdown list when you added the outlet. For me it wasn't since I had to type it in myself.

[image: No custom class specified screengrab]

**Looking at the dropdown I saw that GADBannerView was available as an option and selected it.**

[image: GADBannerView class available]

After selecting it, the app ran without a hitch, no need to add the linker flag (mine was blank by default) or anything.

Hope this helps someone else!