# Thread 1 signal sigabrt error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When I launch my app the build succeeds, but when almost right in the beginning it crashes and highlights the following:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([yes_or_no_AppDelegate class]));
```

and says:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([yes_or_no_AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Error message in console:

```
[GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I found out that this is the part that is causing the error. If I delete it I'm able to launch the app.

```
[self.bannerView setRootViewController:self];
```

But when i launch the app i don't receive a banner and receive error message in console:

```
Must set the rootViewController property of GADBannerView before calling loadRequest:
```

This is my .h file and the code I've used is from googles demo app on banners:

```
@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate>  {


    GADBannerView *adBanner_;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) GADBannerView *adBanner;
```

and my .m file also from google demo app:

```
@synthesize adBanner = adBanner_;

#pragma mark init/dealloc

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view,
// typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                                 self.view.frame.size.height -
                                 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

    // Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
    self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                    origin:origin]
                     ;

    // Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
    // before compiling.
    self.adBanner.adUnitID = kSampleAdUnitID;
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    [self.bannerView setRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
    self.adBanner.center =
    CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
    [self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    adBanner_.delegate = nil;

}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma mark GADRequest generation

// Here we're creating a simple GADRequest and whitelisting the application
// for test ads. You should request test ads during development to avoid
// generating invalid impressions and clicks.
- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    // Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for the simulator as
    // well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
    request.testDevices =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     // TODO: Add your device/simulator test identifiers here. They are
     // printed to the console when the app is launched.
     nil];
    return request;
}

#pragma mark GADBannerViewDelegate impl

// We've received an ad successfully.
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
[GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Did you type the method name correctly? This means the method you are calling does not exist. More specifically the GADObjectPrivate class does not contain this method.

**The crash when calling changeState: has been asked before. See this question:**

[AdMob crashes with [GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635283/admob-crashes-with-gadobjectprivate-changestate-unrecognized-selector)

Comment: "I found out that this is the part that is causing the error" was stated right below "[GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Then if that is the case right above it he states "Error message in console:"

Comment: the link worked for me when I created a new project, but when I changed it in my current project I recieved 12 errors, any idea?